# Shrinking the mean: distance loss function and risk function

Tags: estimation, regularization, euclidean

I'm reading some slides about the shrinkage of the mean and I cannot understand some results.

Assume an n-dimensional vector $\mathbf{x} \sim N(\mu, I_n)$. We are interested in obtaining an estimate  $\delta = \delta (\mathbf{x})$ of $\mu$. We choose $\delta_0 (\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}$. We define the following loss function using Euclidean distance: $$\ell (\mu, \delta(\mathbf{x})) = \left \| \delta(\mathbf{x}) - \mu \right \| ^2$$ and the following risk function: $$R (\mu, \delta(\mathbf{x}))=\mathbb{E}\left [ \ell (\mu, \delta_0(\mathbf{x}))  \right ]$$ such that for $\delta_0 (\mathbf{x})$ we have: $$R (\mu, \delta_0(\mathbf{x}))=\mathbb{E}\left [ \left \| \mathbf{x} - \mu \right \|^2 \right ] = n.$$
**Here is my first doubt.** Since $\left \| \mathbf{x} - \mu \right \|^2 = (\mathbf{x} - \mu) \cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mu) = (\mathbf{x} - \mu)^\intercal (\mathbf{x} - \mu)$ then shouldn't we have: $$R (\mu, \delta_0(\mathbf{x}))=\mathbb{E}\left [ \left \| \mathbf{x} - \mu \right \|^2 \right ] = \mathbb{E}\left [ (\mathbf{x} - \mu)^\intercal (\mathbf{x} - \mu) \right ]=\mathbb{V}\left [ \mathbf{x} \right ] = I_n$$

---

Now let: $$\delta_\alpha\left ( \mathbf{x} \right ) = \left ( 1- \frac{\alpha}{\left \| \mathbf{x} \right \|^2} \right ) \mathbf{x}.$$ How can I show that, with the above definition of risk and loss function, the following is true: $$R (\mu, \delta_\alpha(\mathbf{x}))=n-2\alpha\mathbb{E}\left ( \frac{\left ( \mathbf{x} - \mu \right )^\intercal \mathbf{x}}{\left \| \mathbf{x}^2 \right \|}  \right )+\alpha ^2 \mathbb{E}\left ( \frac{1}{\left \| \mathbf{x}^2 \right \|} \right )$$